# Assert.IsNotNull() should constrain parameter to class

Tags: c#, value-type, boxing, reference-type

Why is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsNotNull()`
declared as:

```
public static void IsNotNull(Object value)
```

and not:

```
public static void IsNotNull<T>(T value) where T : class
```

I just think that some less experienced developers will pass in a value type thinking that it will throw an exception if the value is 0.

UPDATE:
Is there a way to constrain the parameter to a reference type in C# 1.0?

Comment: @Dan is there another syntax that would have worked?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave yes, the one you are unhappy with :) - the generics were introduced in 2.0 (which is after 1.0/1.1 versions of .Net), before the only option would be to use `object` (see `ArrayList` as another dinosaur).

Comment: If you are going to propose an alternative signature, a much better option would be `void IsNotNull<T>(Nullable<T> value)`, as imo all non-Nullable<T> values should be implied to never equal to `null`.

Comment: How about `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`? With your constrain you can not simply write `Assert.IsNotNull(key)`, because `Dictionary` does not have `class` constrain on `TKey`.

Comment: @Dan: of course, my point is that the function should either work for both Nullable value types and reference types (perhaps using OP's suggestion) or not exist at all. Perhaps I phrased my comment poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the answer to "why" is because generics were not available in C# 1.0 when `Assert.IsNotNull` was written.  Changing it, while arguably (much) more correct, has the potential to break existing code.  For better or worse, Microsoft places a very high priority on keeping existing code working.

Comment: As I stated in a comment on the OP, a much better alternative signature would be `void IsNotNull<T>(Nullable<T> value)`, as values not explicitly declared Nullable should imply and be assumed to never equal to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my updated question. Is there a way to constrain the parameter to a reference type in C# 1.0?

Answer (score 3):

What if one has code which can, in different situations produce non-nullable value types and either or both of nullable value types and reference types?

Aside from there not being a good way to cover both reference types and nullable value types in a constraint, the sort of code I just described is no longer testable for situations where it should not result in null. (E.g. `Enumerable.Max()` can return all of those types, but must never return null if there was at least one non-null value in the sequence, and must return null if the type can be null and the sequence is empty).

Reducing functionality to avoid mistaken use is only valuable if you can show that all such uses are also mistaken. Here that can not only not be shown to be true, but it can be shown to be false.

Answer (score -2):

Because the purpose of the function is to assert that `value != null`, and `null` is a value that is independent of any type parameters, so adding a type parameter would be pointless overhead.

Comment: it wouldn't be pointless because it would stop people passing in value types which is bad because they can never be null.

Comment: I fail to see your reasoning. I think passing a value type to the function is fine, and the assertion will be correct, as the value indeed would not be null.

Comment: yes but that is unintuitive. I assume any developer who passes in a value type to this method doesn't know about boxing and would assume it would throw an exception if the value is 0.

Comment: But that's what documentation is for, and language description moreso. Your assumption is based around the users of the function using it blindly. The C# language has a clear definition for the term "null", and the function documentation for `Assert.IsNotNull` has a clear description of the functions operation.

Comment: how many new developers do you think are going to read the documentation? They may not have learned about boxing/value types/reference types, and they may pass in an int with a value of 0 thinking it will throw an exception.

Comment: This can all be avoided by using the syntax I provided. There is no point in passing in a value type since it will never be null. A test is only good if it is possible for it to validate success and also throw an exception.

Comment: Just because the scenario you are describing could be avoided in one way or another, doesn't necessarily justify using a different signature. TBH, your best bet for getting a good answer on this question is a response from Jon Skeet.

Comment: It completely justifies using a different signature. Think about all the confusion it would avoid? However, as the answer says, this is unfortunately not possible since it would break code because generics didn't exist in C#1.0